# Get the formatted values in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get the formatted value of a cell but there seems no such function in [Google Apps Script' s Range class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range). But I found [getNumberFormat()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getNumberFormat()) function that returns the format of the cell as string. Then I searched for a function that can take a format and a string and return a formatted string. No success. So I decided to roll out one myself. The problem is that the number formats are not documented anywhere. I created a script that would display some number formats.
[image]

Does anyone know how to read them?

Comment: There is some documentation included with the spreadsheet [`TEXT()' function documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lib for that! [SheetConverter library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/sheetconverter).

Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/mogsdad/6455765).

Here's how you could get a single formatted cell:

```
var formattedValue = SheetConverter.convertCell(value, format);
```

You'll find other goodies to convert whole ranges into HTML tables, or generate the HTML for a single cell (including fonts, background colors, text colors, and most other formatting elements).

Disclosure: I'm the library author. But that's not my picture on the "ScriptExamples" site!

Answer (score 1):

Use `getDisplayValue` / `getDisplayValues`

Related

- [Difference between getValue() and getDisplayValue() on google app script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34691425/1595451)

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues