# Difference between getValue() and getDisplayValue() on google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

What is the difference of `range.getDisplayValue()` and `range.getValue()` on Google Apps Script?

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var val1 = sheet.getRange(7,5).getDisplayValue();
var val2 = sheet.getRange(7,5).getValue();
```

`Val1` and `Val2` are both same.

Comment: Mostly applications use a value and a displayValue when they handle technical and "real" information. For example you could have a country dial code field with a display value of "Sri Lanka" and a value of "94".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`getDisplayValue` returns the value as you see in the screen, therefore always a string, while `getValue` returns the value underneath, therefore an object. Which may be a string if the range has text in it.

The difference is more clear if the range has numbers or dates in it. Specially if the spreadsheet locale formats the numbers with commas as decimal separators or if you set custom formats in your ranges.

Answer (score 11):

To add more to Henrique's explanation, here is an example from my experience.

I have a column where I enter time in IST

```
IST     
--------
2:00 AM
```

And when I get the value of that column using,

```
var myTime = range.getValue();
```

which actually returned,

```
Sat Dec 30 1899 01:36:40 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

But range.getDisplayValue() solved my problem which returned what I have entered, 2:00 AM.

Answer (score 3):

**To elaborate more on the accepted answer.**

According to the official documentation.

### [getDisplayValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue):

> Returns the displayed value of the top-left cell in the range. The
> value is a String. The displayed value takes into account date, time
> and currency formatting formatting, including formats applied
> automatically by the spreadsheet's locale setting. Empty cells return
> an empty string.

### [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue):

> Returns the value of the top-left cell in the range. The value may be
> of type `Number`, `Boolean`, `Date`, or `String` depending on the
> value of the cell. Empty cells return an empty string.

### Frequently asked questions in stackoverflow - use cases:

- A valid date object in a sheet would return a date object when using `getValue` but a `string` (respecting the format) when using `getDisplayValue`.
- A valid boolean value in google sheets (`TRUE`, `FALSE`) would return `true`, `false` boolean JavaScript objects when using `getValue` but strings when using `getDisplayValue`. This becomes quite handy when you want you use `if` conditions. You can simply use the object itself `if(sheet.getRange('A1').getValue())` if `A1` contains a boolean value.