# getvalues() returns a complete date in the year 1899 for a cell containing only time

Tags: google-apps-script, datetime-format

If we have only a time in say cell A1 of Google sheets. For example, I have this:

```
8:09:00 AM
```

When I use this to fetch the contents of the cell: sheet.getRange(1, 1).getValue(); 
this is what it returns:

```
Sat Dec 30 1899 08:09:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

Why is this happening? Any way for getvalue() to stop interpreting the data and get the raw data instead?

Note: No special formatting has been set by me for the cell. So I guess the formating is the default (automatic), which is not something I want to change for every cell containing such data. The cells containing such times will not be known apriori in any case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `range.getDisplayValue()` to get the display value as a string.

More details on this can be found here: [Difference between getValue() and getDisplayValue() on google app script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34691425/difference-between-getvalue-and-getdisplayvalue-on-google-app-script)

In short, getvalues returns an object which can be a number,a date or a string. In this case it returns a date object, which why it get formatted differently.