# What is this data type in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Form that stores it's result in google sheets of which the following screen grab I have shown.

[image: screen grab]

Google form is also calculating score and that is why there is this column named `Score` in spreadsheet.

Selected cell at bottom shows `20/30` as value. But on the top field(i.e., highlighted) it just says `20`. I want to read the whole value `20/30` through Google App Scripts. As of now I am only getting 20 through Google App Scripts.

Comment: Please don't use the excel tag where it's not relevant

Comment: @TimWilliams - actually, this does appear to be cross-platform but you're probably right; the [tag:excel] doesn't belong largely due to the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is raw value of *20* in a cell with a custom number format of something like `0\/\3\0`. The author assumes you know the numerator is going to be 30 so that can be hard-coded into any calculation or formula. You can only read the raw value of the displayed numerator (e.g. *20*) unless you grab the cell's number format and parse out the denominator.

**tldr:**

You type in *20* and the cell shows *20/30* but its value remains *20*.

Answer (score 1):

## Short Answer

Use getDisplayValue() instead of getValue().

## Explanation

As was already [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48178540/1595451), what are you seeing is a "number format". It was applied by the integration between Google Forms and Google Sheets.

In order to "get what you see" through Google Apps Script, use getDisplayValue() instead of getValue().

## Related Q/A

[Difference between getValue() and getDisplayValue() on google app script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34691425/1595451)