# How to calculate remaining time in google sheet app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to calculate the time remaining in google sheets app script. Below is my work sheet cells.

[image]

**What I need:**

I need to sum up *estimated working days* which have 100%. In the picture, I need to get 0.3.

**What I've tried:**

```js
var mainWsName = "master";

function myFunction() {  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(mainWsName);
  var values = sheet.getRange('D4:D48').getValues();
  
  var a = values.join().split(',');
 
  Logger.log(a); // [, 1, 1, 1, , ]
}
```

My **status** column starts from *D4* and my estimated working days starts from *C4*.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48180014/555121

Comment: It's not related to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution you are looking for:

```
function myFunction() {
  
 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
 const est_works = sh.getRange('C4:C48').getValues().flat([1]); 
 const status = sh.getRange('D4:D48').getDisplayValues().flat([1]);
  
  var sm = 0;
  status.forEach( (element,index) => {
  if(status[index]=== '100%'){sm+=est_works[index]}             
});

sh.getRange('D2').setValue(sm.toFixed(2))
  
}
```

### Explanation:

I iterate through the **status** column and for every cell that contains the value '100%' I sum it up to the variable `sm`. Then I paste the resulting value to cell **D2** as your screenshot illustrates. Feel free to change the sheet name, in my case *Sheet1*.

Comment: It needs to be explicitly run inside the script editor. How can I update that **D2** column whenever I edit that *status* range which is *D4:D48*.

Comment: @HtetPhyoNaing what do you mean? You can just edit it to the cell of your preference. E.g. `getRange('D3')` for example

Comment: In my screen shot, let' say I update *D4* to *100%*. I need to get update *D3* to **2.3** automatically. In the current code, it does not.

Comment: I see. If you want a value to be changed whenever you edit a particular cell you should use onEdit() triggers. Please post another question to ask particularly for an onEdit trigger of your function and I will be able to answer it. @HtetPhyoNaing

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I updated `myFunction` to `onEdit` and it works now.