# Trim without turning some numerical values into date values Google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, trim

I have

```
var rangeValues = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
// iterate through all cells in the selected range
for (var cellRow = 0; cellRow < maxHeight; cellRow++) {
 for (var cellColumn = 0; cellColumn < maxWidth; cellColumn++) {  
    rangeValues[cellRow][cellColumn] = rangeValues[cellRow][cellColumn].toString().trim();
 }
}
```

and it turns some numerical values into date values

Ex:

8055-1 >> `Fri Jan 01 8055 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST)`

I think the issue is `toString()` not `trim()`

Is there a way to trim to avoid this problem?

Thanks

Comment: How is `rangeValues` defined?

Comment: ross, I just added that

Comment: Have you checked the cell's formatting? Is it set to any sort of "date" format?

Comment: I have `no` date formates set anywhere on the sheet

Comment: What's `maxHeight` ? What's `maxWidth`? If we can't run your code to verify the problem then it's difficult for us to provide assistance. Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution, if the value of a cell is changed from `8055-1` to `Fri Jan 01 8055 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST)` when the value is retrieved by `getValues()`, I think that the reason of your issue is that `8055-1` is used as the date object. In that case, for example, how about using `getDisplayValues()` instead of `getValues()`? But I'm not sure about the detail of your situation. If this was not the result you want, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet? By this, I would like to think of the issue.

Comment: @tanaike, thank you this `getDisplayValues()` worked great

Comment: For anyone coming to this in need of help, here is a helpful post on this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34691425/difference-between-getvalue-and-getdisplayvalue-on-google-app-script`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
function trimCells(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rangeValues = sheet.getDataRange().setNumberFormat("@").getValues();
  // iterate through all cells in the selected range
  for (var cellRow = 0; cellRow < rangeValues.length; cellRow++) {
    for (var cellColumn = 0; cellColumn < rangeValues[0].length; cellColumn++) {  
      Logger.log("Before: " + rangeValues[cellRow][cellColumn])
      rangeValues[cellRow][cellColumn] = rangeValues[cellRow][cellColumn];
      Logger.log("After: " + rangeValues[cellRow][cellColumn])
    }
  }
}
```

Adding the `setNumberFormat("@")` to the range will make the range you selected into plain text. When you added the values to the sheet before, they were getting formatted as dates automatically because it matched the pattern. with this change you make it so that the format of the range is set as plain text.

Also, I changed `maxHeight` and `maxWidth` based on the length of `rangeValues` I'm assuming that's also how you got them. This code will set the values in the range to plain text and retrieve them, you won't even need `toString()` or `trim()` (unless you actually want the latter).

Comment: Alberto, thank you. this is a fine approach, it workehed as hoped